# Junit test cases of non public class

Tags: java

I have a class as following

```
package a.b
public class Public_Class{
  public void add(){
    //logic
  }
}
class Non_Public_Class{
  public void subt(){
    //any logic
  }
}
package a.c
```

Now I want to make test cases of method `subt()` in "Non_Public_Class".

How can I access that non public class and my test cases are not in the same package?

Answer (score 6):

You should follow the now (more or less) standards for directory structures that tools like maven [suggest](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). Meaning:

You can have

- src/main/java ... and here go all your production code packages
- src/test/java ... and here go all the test packages (which then can have the **same** names as your production packages)

That allows you to write unit test for "package protected" stuff.

Comment: you even beat Jon here !  :)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access that non public class and my test cases are not in the same package.

Change that, basically. It's pretty common practice (at least as far as I've seen) to keep your production and test classes in separate source hierarchies, but still put them into the same Java packages - precisely so you can then test package-access classes easily.

(I'd definitely still split them into different source hierarchies, that output to different class directories, too, so that you don't need to package your test code with your production code.)